# Ubuntu VM Full disk encryption, storing keys in Azure

Tags: boot, encryption, keyrings, active-directory, azure

We currently have a solution to have our data partition encrypted with the keys stored on the system partition to allow for booting without user interaction, but not our system partition as we have no clue how to integrate our Ubuntu VMs into Active Directory, which can store the encryption keys in the Azure Key vault?

*Has anyone else ever done this before* and if yes: **how?**